# How can I get login page link to work after I click on a sign in button in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, localhost, local-storage

I am creating a sign-in and registration page on a PHP project.
I have created the forms in HTML, however, I need to link it to the main header file in PHP, so that it works on all other sections of the page. When I click the button, it redirects me to a blank page.

Here is a copy of my code;

The Header

```
<div id="top-header">
<img src="/phpmotors/images/site/logo.png" alt="PHP Motors logo" id="logo">
<a href="/phpmotors/accounts/index.php?action=login.php" title="Login or Register with PHP Motors" id="acc">My Account</a>
```

Controller..Index.PHP

```
// Get the database connection file
require_once '../library/connections.php';
// Get the PHP Motors model for use as needed
require_once '../model/main-model.php';

//Get the array of classifications from the database using the model.
$classifications = getClassifications();

 
// Build a navigation bar using the $classifications array
$navList = '<ul>';
$navList .= "<li><a href='/phpmotors/index.php' title='View the PHP Motors home page'>Home</a></li>";
foreach ($classifications as $classification) {
 $navList .= "<li><a href='/phpmotors/index.php?action=".urlencode($classification['classificationName'])."
 ' title='View our $classification[classificationName] product line'>$classification[classificationName]</a></li>";
}
$navList .= '</ul>';



$action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
if ($action == NULL) {
  $action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
}

//Get the database of login information
$clientEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientEmail');
$clientPassword = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientPassword');


//Get the database of registration information
$clientFirst = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientFirstname');
$clientLast = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientLast');
$clientEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientEmail');
$clientPassword = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientPassword');


switch ($action) {
  case 'login':
    include 'view\login.php';
    break;
  case 'registration':
    include 'view\registration.php';

default:
    include 'view/home.php';
}
?>
</div>
```

Forms HTML

```
   <h1>Sign in</h1>
        <form action="/accounts/" method="POST">
            <label>Email</label>
            <br>
            <input name="clientEmail" id="clientEmail" type="email" <?php if(isset($clientEmail)){echo "value='$clientEmail'";}  ?> required>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label>Password</label>
            <br>
            <input name="clientPassword" id="clientPassword" type="password">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="regbtn" value="Login">
            <!-- Add the action name - value pair -->
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Login">
        </form>
        <p>
            <a href = "/accounts/index.php/?action=registration">Not a member yet?</a>
        </p>
```

Comment: Is `/phpmotors` supposed to be the DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: Yes, it is. It is the main folder that contains the rest of the other files and folders.

Comment: my guess is that you have a configuration error as you would never typically have the root folder in any url. The `/accounts/index.php` page, for instance, is a root relative link - it should not need or indeed use the `/phpmotors` portion of the path

Comment: It did not work out.
I had the the following errors:

Warning: include(view/home.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmotors\accounts\index.php on line 53

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'view/home.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmotors\accounts\index.php on line 53

Comment: In your header file you use the `login.php` action and in your `index.php` you expect just `login`, without `.php`. Maybe that will change something.